# How to use external library in my own Arduino library?

Tags: c++, arduino, avr, hardware

Good evening!

I'm writing an Arduino library. Inside it, I want to instantiate an object from another library whose constructor needs to be passed a parameter, but I don't want to hard-code such parameter. I need some guidance about how to do this.

Here's the relevant part of my code so far:

HSBC_CAN.h:

```
class HSBC_CAN {

    public:
        HSBC_CAN(uint8_t, uint8_t);

    private:
        uint8_t _int_pin;

};
```

HSBC_CAN.cpp:

```
#include <HSBC_CAN.h>
#include <mcp_can.h>

extern MCP_CAN *canbus_esc;

HSBC_CAN::HSBC_CAN(uint8_t int_pin, uint8_t cs_pin) {

    _int_pin = int_pin;
    canbus_esc = new MCP_CAN(cs_pin);

}
```

To be clear, the way to instantiate an object from MCP_CAN class is `MCP_CAN foo(int bar)`, where `bar` is the chip select pin number for SPI protocol. I want my library to instantiate an object of MCP_CAN class but I need to be able to pass the chip select pin number when instantiating an object from my new class HSBC_CAN. This is the error I get with the above code:

```
error: request for member 'begin' in 'canbus_esc', which is of pointer type 'MCP_CAN*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)
```

Probably the way I did in my sample code is totally wrong (with the `extern` keyword and the `new` operator) but that's just what came out from my mind ATM.

Thanks for the time.

Comment: You didn't post the line that was actually generating the error.  In the future, please post all the code, *especially* the line that is giving you the error.  In this case, the error message from the compiler was good enough that I had a pretty good idea about what you did wrong but that is usually not the case.

Answer (score 0):

The error message from the compiler is very useful and if you would follow its advice of replacing `.` with `->` it would probably fix your immediate problem.  Since `canbus_esc` is a pointer, you must dereference it before accessing its members or functions.  So if it has a function named `begin` that can be called with zero arguments, you might write:

```
canbus_esc->begin();
```

That line is equivalent to:

```
(*canbus_esc).begin();
```

Also, get rid of the word `extern` on the line that defined `canbus_esc`, or else you will get an undefined reference error for it.

However, I have two issues with the code you have presented:  First of all, you are using `new`, which does dynamic memory allocation.  It's a good idea to avoid dynamic memory allocation on small devices like AVRs if you can, since you never know if those allocations are going to fail until you actually run the program (you might be using up too much memory in other parts of your program).  Secondly, you defined your `canbus_esc` at the file scope, so there can only be one of them.  This means you can't really create multiple `HSBC_CAN` objects; the second one will overwrite the `canbus_esc` create by the first.  Although that might be fine for your application, it seems like a needless limitation.

I'd suggest writing your code like this instead:

Header file:

```cpp
#include <mcp_can.h>
class HSBC_CAN {
public:
  HSBC_CAN(uint8_t int_pin, uint8_t cs_pin);
  void begin();
private:
  uint8_t _int_pin;
  MCP_CAN can;
};
```

Source file:

```cpp
#include <HSBC_CAN.h>

HSBC_CAN::HSBC_CAN(uint8_t int_pin, uint8_t cs_pin)
  : can(cs_pin)  // This line constructs the MCP_CAN object
{
  _int_pin = int_pin;
}

HSBC_CAN::begin()
{
  can.begin(42, 42, 42);  // TODO: fix arguments
}
```

Another idea, which might be better, would be for you to have your HSBC_CAN object take a pointer to an MBC_CAN object and store the pointer as a member variable in the HSBC_CAN class.  That option would make a lot of sense if there are multiple devices on the CAN bus that you want to talk to using that MBC_CAN object.  You could have multiple classes using a single MBC_CAN object via pointers.